# Starting solr as root user on ubuntu without any errors

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I try to install Hybris on ubuntu. But I get the following error :

```
[java] WARNING: Starting Solr as the root user is a security risk and not considered best practice. Exiting.
[java] Please consult the Reference Guide. To override this 
 check, start with argument '-force'
```

when I type :

> sudo ant updatesystem

there is any solution to solve this problem without creating a new user ?

I try :

> sudo ant updatesystem -force

but it didn't work
Any help please and thank you.

Comment: Why do you start hybris with root user? It is general a bad practice to use root for such things.

Comment: ok so i have to create an other user or what ?

Comment: Yes, on linux systems is not good the use the root user for general purpose.

Comment: ok thanks Hristo Staykov

Comment: @Mostafa - As `Hrusto` said, you should have a different user for your Hybris application setup. Find my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

### Why you should avoid running applications as root

I've often come across posts on forums or other websites where you see people joking in such a manner about running/logging in as root as if it's something awful and everyone ought to know about it. However, there isn't much that a search reveals on the matter.

It may be widely known to Linux experts, but I really don't know why. I remember always running as root when I first tried Linux years ago (Redhat and Mandrake) and don't remember running into any problems because of that.

There are actually some distros that have a bright red background with alert signs all over it as wallpaper for the root user (SuSe?). I still use the "Administrator" account for regular use on my Windows installation and haven't ever run into any problems there either.
[[source]](https://askubuntu.com/q/16178/679136)

---

### How to create a User Account on Linux systems for Hybris Setup?

1. Open a shell prompt.
2. If you are not logged in as root, type the command su - and enter
   the root password.
3. Type useradd followed by a space and the username for the new
   account you are creating at the command line (for example, useradd
   jsmith). Press [Enter]. Often, usernames are variations on the
   user's name, such as jsmith for John Smith. User account names can
   be anything from the user's name, initials, or birthplace to
   something more creative.
4. Type passwd followed by a space and the username again (for example,
   passwd jsmith).
5. At the New password: prompt enter a password for the new user and
   press [Enter].
6. At the Retype new password: prompt, enter the same password to
   confirm your selection.

---

### You can find [detail post here](https://hybrisdeveloper.blogspot.in/2018/03/how-to-setup-user-account-on-linux.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to force start solr. Because solr started by bean in hybris. You can try extend buildCommonSolrCommandParams metod in AbstractSolrServerController class which is setting solr parameters. You need "-force" as first command in this metod.

Answer (score 0):

How-to: Hack up Hybris 6.4+ to run Solr as root.

This can be done by simply editing:
hybris/bin/ext-commerce/solrserver/resources/solr/bin/solr

Replace:
FORCE=false

With:
FORCE=true

Once done, restart Hybris. You'll see that Solr will now start up, even though Hybris is now running as root.